# Expression of type sql.DataFrame does not conform the expected type Option[sql.DataFrame]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following function in Scala:

```
  def getData(spark: SparkSession,
              indices: Option[String]): Option[DataFrame] = {

    indices match {
      case None => {
        println("Undefined field.")
        None
      }
      case Some(ind) => {
        val df = spark
          .read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
          .load(ind)
        df
      }
    }
}
```

However, I get the compilation error:

> Expression of type sql.DataFrame does not conform the expected type
>   Option[sql.DataFrame]

I tried to return `Option[df]`, but it compiles neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the wrong type:

```
  def getData(spark: SparkSession,
              indices: Option[String]): Option[DataFrame] = {

    indices match {
      case None => {
        println("Undefined field.")
        None
      }
      case Some(ind) => {
        val df = spark
          .read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
          .load(ind)
        Some(df) // <- Here!!!
      }
    }
}
```

or more idiomatically

```
indicies.map{
  ind =>
    spark
      .read
      .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .load(ind)
}
```

Comment: The second option looks cool. Can you please explain it a bit more or post some reference with examples?

Comment: https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html - I suggest reading this whole series of articles.

Comment: Maybe you could help with this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813910/how-to-deal-with-none-output-of-a-function-in-scala
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `df` into `Some`:

```
def getData(spark: SparkSession,
              indices: Option[String]): Option[DataFrame] = {

    indices match {
      case None => {
        println("Undefined field.")
        None
      }
      case Some(ind) => {
        val df = spark
          .read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
          .load(ind)
        Some(df) // here
      }
    }
```