# How to deal with None output of a function in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following function:

```
 def getData(spark: SparkSession,
             indices: Option[String]): Option[DataFrame] = {

    indices.map{
      ind =>
        spark
          .read
          .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
          .load(ind)
    }

  }
```

This function returns `Option[DataFrame]`.

Then I want to use this function as follows:

```
val df = getData(spark, indices)
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Of course the last two lines of code will not compile because `df` might be `None`. What is the idiomatic way deal with `None` output in Scala?
I would like to throw an exception and stop the program if `df` is None. Otherwise I want to `persist` it.

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/jankrag/introduction-to-option-monad-in-scala

Comment: you can use flatMap

Answer (score 5):

If you do care about the `None` I'd use simple pattern match here:

```
df match {
  case None => throw new RuntimeException()
  case Some(dataFrame) => dataFrame.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
}
```

But if you don't care, just use foreach like:

```
df.foreach { dataFrame =>
  dataFrame.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val df = dfOption.getOrElse(throw new Exception("Disaster Strikes"))
df.persist(...)
```